# Linq query - Skip next query execution on condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have linq statement to execute the function.

```
return
                    from _1 in CheckNoConnectWithSelf(userId, new(request.UserFromId))
                    from _10 in CheckScopes(request.Scopes)
                    let userIdFrom = new UserId(request.UserFromId)
                    from _2 in CheckUserFromAsync(userIdFrom).ToAsync()
                    from invitationId in CheckValidAcceptAsync(userIdFrom, userId).ToAsync()
                    from _3 in CheckAlreadyConnectedAsync(userIdFrom, userId).ToAsync()
                    from transaction in BeginTransactionAsync().ToAsync()
                    from _4 in StoreConnectionAsync(userIdFrom, userId, invitationId, request.Status).ToAsync()
                    from _5 in CreateNewsEntryAsync(userIdFrom, userId).ToAsync()
                    from groupId in CreatePersonalGroupAsync(userIdFrom, userId).ToAsync()
                    from _6 in CreatePersonalChatAsync(groupId).ToAsync()
                    from _7 in AddGroupMemberAsync(groupId, userId).ToAsync()
                    //from _8 in AddGroupMemberAsync(groupId, userIdFrom).ToAsync()
                    from _9 in GrantScopesAsync(userId, userIdFrom, request.Scopes).ToAsync()
                    from _99 in CommitTransactionAsync(transaction).ToAsync()
                    select unit;
```

here if I want to skip few steps like if there is specific value in the request I don't want to execute _6, _7 _8 and _9 and directly call _99
I have been trying to add if else but I don't want to put if else in every function.

Explaination for each function CheckNoConnectWithSelf -> Check some validations from the request and throws exception if something is invalid
and returns unit if its fine
CheckScopes does the same and CheckUserFromAsync check if the user is valid by doing a db query.
CheckValidAcceptAsync - Also makes db query and returns some value which will be used in next functions
BeginTransactionAsync starts a db transaction and returns transaction which will be used to commit transaction in CommitTransaction.
Other functions in the middle will Save/Update the db.
For Eg-

```
private async Task<Either<GroupCreateResultStatus, GroupId>> CreatePersonalGroupAsync
                (GroupCreateRequest groupCreateRequest, UserId userId, GroupTypeDb groupType)
            {
                var user = await logic_.users_.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);

                var cryptor = Cryptor<GroupId>.Create(logic_.scopeRepository_, userId);
                var dek = Cryptor<GroupId>.GenerateKey();
                var salt = cryptor.GenerateSalt();

                var connectionRequest = new GroupDb
                {
                    CreatedBy = user.Id,
                    OwnedBy = user.Id,
                    GroupType = groupType,
                    Name = new(cryptor, dek, salt, groupCreateRequest.GroupName),
                    CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = GroupStatusDb.Active
                };

                var group = await logic_.repository_.AddAsync(connectionRequest);
                var groupId = new GroupId(group.Id);

                // TODO REI 20200124 Write dek and salt

                return groupId;
            }
```

This function create a record and return id which will be used in other functions

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're creating an 11-dimensional Cartesian product here and then do nothing with it (`select unit`). That looks like a useless operation, unless each method changes state somewhere. What *exactly* is this code supposed to do? It looks like you should convert it to sequential calls, so you can easily skip some depending on the outcome of previous ones.

Comment: each statement is making a change in the db and I am throwing exception if any execution fails and no need to do anything if everything goes well hence unit.
I am saving / updating in methods from BeginTransaction to CommitTransaction I want to skip few methods if request.Status has somevalue it does not depend on the outcome of the previos one

Comment: These are not db queries @TimSchmelter these are just sequential methods being executed.

Comment: I am new to this project and to C# as well 
this structure has been followed by other developers and according to them this is an efficient way to do 
let me explain all the functions in the question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can check the updated question for more information

Comment: @GertArnold Looks like OP is using [this kind of trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wesdyer/the-marvels-of-monads) to do it, so each `from` only returns a single object. But honestly, it's the most berserk thing to do, unless you were actually converting Haskell code into C#. Not a single other person here is going to understand it, and you're unlikely to get any help with it.

Comment: In answer, not sure, but I suppose you could return an empty object (of whatever your monad is) instead of `BeginTransaction`. Like `from transaction in (mycondition ? NoTransaction() : BeginTransactionAsync().ToAsync())` maybe? Guessing in the dark here

Comment: @Charlieface it actually worked thanks

Comment: @Charlieface Good catch. In fact, using LINQ as monads can be really great, but at least it should require some explanation in the question.